How to face 'warning' in pine script v5 code
I'm a beginner with pine script and working on a Pine Script v5 code and need some help. want to create a script that takes "length from" and "length to" values from the user. For each length within this range, I want to calculate simple moving average using ta.sma for each bar of historical data and then perform some calculations using these SMA values. However, I've encountered a warning that says:
"Warning at 19:11 The function 'ta.sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope"
Below is the basic structure of my script.
Thanks in advance!
    //@version=5
    indicator("SMA Range Processor", overlay=true)

    // User inputs for length range
    length_from = input.int(5, title="Length From")
    length_to = input.int(37, title="Length To")

    // Function to perform calculations (currently does nothing)
    calcSmaAndDoCalculations(smaValue,barIndex) =>
        // Placeholder for actual calculations
        smaValue

    // Pre-compute all SMAs
    var smaValues = array.new_float()
    var float smaValue = 0.00

    for length = length_from to length_to
        // Calculate the SMA for the current length and store it
        sma = ta.sma(close, length)
        array.push(smaValues, sma)

    // Loop through the specified range of lengths
    for length = 0 to array.size(smaValues) - 1
        // Get the pre-computed SMA for the current length
        smaValue := array.get(smaValues, length)
        // Loop through each bar in the historical data
        for barIndex = 0 to bar_index
            // Call the calculation function with the SMA value
            result = calcSmaAndDoCalculations(smaValue,barIndex)

    plot(close, title="Close Price")

My question is how can I avoid above warning from above code? Or I have to avoid use of 'ta.sma' within 'for loop? Or is there any alternate way exists to do that?
I also tried custom SMA function, that too not worked.If i ignore this warning, then code does not gives any result.(Stops working).
Now if given range is 7..46 then I have to use sma of each length in my code as following:
your text
    ta.sma(close,7)
    ta.sma(close,8)
    ta.sma(close,9)
    ...........
    ...........
    ta.sma(close,46)


How can I do that without using 'FOR LOOP'?

AI-generated code is inconsistent, buggy, and unreliable. Artificial Intelligence is very useful in many aspects, but it encodes Pinescript very poorly (for now...).
Consequently, TradingView and the PineCoders community have decided to not provide support to fix GPT-related code.
